# how to show menu item under overflow icon in android api 8+

Tags: android, android-actionbar, android-menu, android-actionbar-compat

How I can force menu item to show under overflow icon. I am providing app support from api level 8 and above. for now it is showing as actionview .
My menuLayout is as follows.

```
 //main.xml
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto" >

<item
    android:id="@+id/action_menu_setting"
    android:title="@string/menuItemSetting"
    app:showAsAction="ifRoom"/>
<item
    android:id="@+id/action_signout"
    android:title="@string/menuItemLogout"
    app:showAsAction="ifRoom"/>
 </menu>
```

in Java class

```
 @Override
 public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
    inflater.inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
    return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
    }
```

I have tried with other options of `showAsAction` but none of them worked. Please suggest me how I can show above two menu itme under `overflow` icon(when i click on over these two will appearer as actionlist.)

Comment: change this app:showAsAction="ifRoom"  to app:showAsAction="never"

Comment: in that case the overflow icon is not visible in android api <11.

Comment: If device possess menu button overflow icon will not show, that is for sure

Comment: Is there any documents related to `If device possess menu button overflow icon will not show`. If you know plz give me link.

Comment: Android 4.0 brings these changes for tablets to the phone platform.http://developer.android.com/design/patterns/compatibility.html

Comment: Or you can use trick given at http://stackoverflow.com/a/20544009/2819233

Comment: Or you can create a custom layout for action bar and then add a button in that layout and show pop up for ur menu things

Comment: http://blog.vogella.com/2013/08/06/android-always-show-the-overflow-menu-even-if-the-phone-as-a-menu/ always show the overflow menu even if the phone has a menu

Answer (score 1):

Could you post java code ? Do you have code below in your activity ?

```
@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu, menu);;
    return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
}
```

Edit : 
I alway use code like this(when i click action_settings it will show action list contains setting and bar, i think just replace android:title="@string/action_settings" with android:icon)

```
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >
    <item
        android:id="@+id/action_settings"
        android:orderInCategory="100"
        android:showAsAction="always"
        android:title="@string/action_settings">
         <menu>
            <item 
                android:enabled="true" 
                android:visible="true" 
                android:title="setting" 
                android:id="@+id/setting">
            </item>
            <item 
                android:enabled="true" 
                android:visible="true" 
                android:title="B" 
                android:id="@+id/bar">
            </item>
        </menu>
    </item>
     <item
        android:id="@+id/action_settings1"
        android:orderInCategory="100"
        android:showAsAction="always"
        android:title="@string/action_settings"/>
</menu>
```

Hope it helps

Comment: If you read my question I have mention that `For now it is showing as actionview`. MenuItem is showing my friend but as actionview I want it as ActionList under overflow icon.

Answer (score 1):

layout for custom action bar

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="?android:attr/actionBarSize"
    android:background="@drawable/header"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tvActionBarTitle"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="?android:attr/actionBarSize"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
        android:textSize="30sp" />

    <Button.../>
<!--     your code for button -->
</LinearLayout>
```

You can call below function in onCreate and define button in this function as I have defined appName text view and its OnClick event

```
 private void createCutomActionBarTitle()
        {
            if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.ICE_CREAM_SANDWICH)
            {
                this.getActionBar().setHomeButtonEnabled(true);
            }
            this.getActionBar().setDisplayShowCustomEnabled(true);
            this.getActionBar().setDisplayShowTitleEnabled(false);
            this.getActionBar().setBackgroundDrawable(drawable);
            this.getActionBar().setIcon(logo);
            LayoutInflater inflator = LayoutInflater.from(this);
            View v = inflator.inflate(R.layout.custom_action_bar, null);

            ((TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.tvActionBarTitle)).setText(Global.ACTIVITY_NAME);

            this.getActionBar().setCustomView(v);
        }
```

Hope this will be useful for you :)
But clicking physical button of device will not trigger this button you have to look for it, as I don't have any idea about it

Comment: there is answer for physical button at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20311353/android-actionbar-compat-overflow-menu-not-showing-on-sdk-10