# Android: ActionBar action overflow is not shown in Android 4.3, Samsung Note 2

Tags: android, android-actionbar

We switching back to showing [Actionbar](https://developer.android.com/training/appbar)

[image]
<sub>(source: [android.com](https://developer.android.com/images/ui/actionbar@2x.png))</sub>

But  [3] action overflow menu is not shown (in Android 4.3, Samsung Note 2).

```
<uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="15"
    android:targetSdkVersion="19" />
```

Activity class `extends android.app.Activity` (not ActionBarActivity)

I played to even setting all menu item to have `android:showAsAction="never"` (In that case no actions are on ActionBar)

Docs

- http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/menu-resource.html

Similar questions when using appcompat support library

- [Android ActionBar compat overflow menu not showing on sdk 10](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20311353/android-actionbar-compat-overflow-menu-not-showing-on-sdk-10)
- [how to show menu item under overflow icon in android api 8+](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27101581/how-to-show-menu-item-under-overflow-icon-in-android-api-8?lq=1)

EDIT `common_actions.xml` has all actions as `android:showAsAction="never"`

```
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >

    <item
        android:id="@+id/action_home"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_default_image"
        android:showAsAction="never"
        android:title="@string/recommend"
        />
    <item
        android:id="@+id/action_downloadmanager"
        android:icon="@drawable/icon_personal_light_download_manage"
        android:showAsAction="never"
        android:title="@string/downloadmanage"
        />
    <item
        android:id="@+id/action_search"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_action_search"
        android:showAsAction="never"
        android:title="@string/search"
        />
    <item
        android:id="@+id/action_settings"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_action_settings"
        android:showAsAction="never"
        android:title="@string/setting"
        />

</menu>
```

Comment: Can you post your menu.xml code?

Answer (score 3):

This is a Samsung thing that's actually a reaaaaallly stupid UI decision in my opinion. Within Touchwiz for all versions AFAIK overflow in the ActionBar isn't supported, instead you have to hit the bottom left button where a Gingerbread-esque menu pops up.

[image]

With Toolbar in AppCompat though you can override that behaviour and it shows a normal overflow in your ActionBar, I wrote a short post about moving from ActionBar to Toolbar that you can check out [here](https://medium.com/@drkcsm/moving-from-actionbar-to-toolbar-f041f7542557), which contains links to more resources.

Comment: OK, so there is Samsung Touchwiz related issues. In the question I pointed that AppCompat  is not used. Nice piece of info but not answer.

Comment: AppCompat is used, but you're not targeting Lollipop or using Toolbar instead of ActionBar which would solve your issue. Sorry if I didn't word that clearly.

Comment: > Activity class extends android.app.Activity (not ActionBarActivity).  

Thanks anyway

Answer (score 0):

Looking further I have found a similar question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23906985/action-overflow-button-not-shown (and [here too](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18237450/best-way-to-show-the-three-dot-menu-item-in-action-bar-without-using-a-hack-me))

that actually lead to several options inside [Android action bar not showing overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9739498/android-action-bar-not-showing-overflow)

I went with

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    makeOverflowMenu();
}

private void makeOverflowMenu() {
    //devices with hardware menu button don't show action overflow menu
    try {
        ViewConfiguration config = ViewConfiguration.get(this);
        Field menuKeyField = ViewConfiguration.class.getDeclaredField("sHasPermanentMenuKey");
        if (menuKeyField != null) {
            menuKeyField.setAccessible(true);
            menuKeyField.setBoolean(config, false);
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        Log.d(TAG, e.getLocalizedMessage());
    }
}
```

Hardware menu button on Samsung Note 2 acts as if ActionBar action overflow menu was pressed.

Answer (score 0):

*That is correct behavior.*

If you have a physical menu button (Samsung has it), Android will automatically hide the three dots.
If you don't, it will show them.

Comment: I like more when physical menu button acts as if action overflow menu was pressed, as I did.